# Downgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, downgrade

So yesterday (2014-07-27) I upgraded my machines from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, thinking the 14.04.1 point-release is out.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Didn't show a new release so I did

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
```

Now I found out, that this upgraded to 14.04.4 instead of 14.04.1.

My question: Can I downgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04.1 (or 14.04)? If yes, how do I do this?

Update:

I have updated 3 machines and I can't remember why I thought I had them upgraded to the no-yet-existing 14.04.4 `lsb_release -a` on all of them and they all report:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty.
```

Sorry for wasting your time. :-/

Comment: 14.04.4 does not exist yet: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-14.04.4 Release date is 8th of januari 2016: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DraftReleaseSchedule  Proof please you have a .4

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not sure if it was `lsb-release -a` that revealed that I had 14.04.4 installation. I know that 14.04.4 hasn't any packages of it's own yet. But I don't wan't to get those packages when they are released. I'd like to stay with 14.04.1 even on 2016-01. How do I do this?

Comment: The version 14.04.4 don't even exist. I think you might have read it wrong. Check it again.

Comment: @Dishank I'm going to check as soon as I can access the machine. Sorry of being vague here. I'm commenting here as soon I have the info.

Comment: You can check about version 14.04.4 here. http://milodovic.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-4-lts/

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsb_release -a` if you have a .4 release you have 12.04.4 LTS

Comment: Updated question text. Seems I have made a fool of myself :-/

Comment: Don't worry, everyone does :) just be prepared to be laughed at in the chat possibly...

Comment: You probably had already updated 12.04 previously to 12.04.4, and got that number mixed up with the 14.04.1.

Comment: @Tim I've developed some thicker skin while reading newsgroups, IRC, slashdot and 4chan. Never had a chat in AskUbuntu though... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by OP in comments.

I read this wrong, I do actually have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS:

```
$ lsb_release -a    
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty.
```

OP apologised:

Sorry for wasting your time. :-/